# iTunes Connect not showing my uploaded IPA

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I want to add a new version for my iOS application. I created a new version tab for my app in the iTunes Connect, set the information required, save them. Then I go to Xcode and make a archive, validate it and the pressed submit for Appstore.

After a few minutes the process done successfully but in the iTunes Connect no build appear and I can not "Submit to review". Under builds section it keeps saying: "Submit your builds using Xcode 5.1.1 or later, or Application Loader 3.0 or later."

What is the problem?

Comment: How long did you wait after completing the upload? Usually you have to wait at least a couple of minutes (or even 5 to 10) and then the submitted IPA appears in the list when clicking on the '+' button.

Comment: It is more than 1 hour and I repeat the process several times. Also there is not any plus button near the build section. Only the message

Comment: Have you tried uploading the IPA using the Application Loader (find the .dmg on iTunes Connect)? Lately I had much better luck with it than with Xcode's "Submit to AppStore".

Comment: If your ipa size is more then it takes some time to reflect at build section, So after 10-15min refresh your browser login in again and keep patience.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For those that have uploaded their app through Xcode, but don't see it under the 'Build' heading on the 'App Store' tab, do the follow.

Go to the `Activity` tab and it will show you a list of builds for your app. You should see the app you just uploaded in this list and it will say that it is `(Processing)`.

Wait about 15 - 20 mins for it to process and then you can continue on with listing your app.

Comment: It disappears after processing complete

Comment: I have the same problem. Binary disappears when uploaded to iTunes. IT shows processing for few seconds and then gone!

Answer (score 9):

If we upload from Xcode 8, we need to check if any privacy keys to be added in the `info.plist`.

Like, `NSCameraUsageDescription`,`NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`,`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`,`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`.

In my app I missed to add `NSCalendarsUsageDescription`.

We should also add description for the key. If not, the build won't appear in itunesconnect.

Hope, this will help someone.

Comment: Same. My info.plist got override by cordova, changing the NSCalendarsUsageDescription to an empty string instead of my actual description. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: These are called purpose strings. if the app uses Apis in code but misses out mentioning appropriate keys in info.plist , even though status for app upload shows success. they will never be visible in App store connected. happenend with me on Xcode 12.4

Answer (score 8):

Also sometimes the problem send to your email. You should check it because there is no caution in your Xcode loader or iTunes console. Even you can't find any activity under the activity tab

Comment: Apple sent me notice as I was missing 4 private keys with details.

Comment: @AmitBravo: yes this is a common mistake

Comment: this helped me don't know why i forgot about it, thanks

Answer (score 3):

After submitting the ipa to appstore it will take minimum 15 - 30 min for showing in "Select a build before you submit your app." so till that you can monitor processing of your app in "Activity" tab.

Answer (score 3):

Check your mail account, if there any issue apple sends you mail to your mail account associated with your developer account.

This was my silly simple way to know the issue in the uploaded file.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your iTunes -> Prerelease tab, then you can see your uploaded build. It will be processing state. Please give it 15 minutes, and it will be ready to add from your app Version tab -> Build area.

Comment: there is not any thing in the prerelease tab only the message: "Submit your builds using Xcode 5.1.1 or later, or Application Loader 3.0 or later."

Comment: if your prerelease tab showing not anything , please upload again a build using Xcode or Application Loader

Comment: I repeat the process several time but any changes do not appears

Comment: Please share the screenshot after successfully uploaded from Xcode or Application Loaded .

Comment: Did you review updated Terms & Condition/ Agreements, Tax, and Banking from apple and Accept them. Do that from both account Apple Developer Account & Itunes Connect

Comment: your build not uploaded unless same build & version you never can uploaded again . share screen which may clear what happen

Comment: The problem was because I had choose a provisioning profile that was not for distributation

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad: I think you should try by updating version number and build number, the same thing happens with me sometimes. May be this will work for you also.

Comment: If u upload build with same version number and build number Xcode will inform you that "binary is already exist" if you came across this message that means your build is upload, if iTunes does not showing your build then change version number and try to upload it again

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad , I am facing similar problem, how/where did you know you using wrong provisioning profile, I had two profiles one for developement and one for distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using Xcode Beta. For the newer versions of Xcode, it expects you to archive and upload using the stable version. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, my solution is to use the Application Loader and it has working for me.

Comment: Loader not able to sing in because of 2FA(two factor authentication), onwards 2FA is enable and we can't disable.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem ... then I add .

```
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) bluetooth use.</string>
```

in `info.plist` file and again upload it will display in 20-30 minutes.